EFHW Antenna Analysis: Should phase at the antenna feedpoint be similar to the phase presented to the TXRX?
I have a 30m EFHW resonant sloper antenna.  I've completed tuning it using my RigExpert and have an excellent SWR at the antenna and the TXRX.  I know that some common mode currents are present, so I have a CMC filter at the antenna and in the shack.  I've attached an image showing the antenna system and antenna analysis at five locations.
I have two quick questions:

After the signal passes through the shack's CMC filter at the end of a 50' run of LMR400, should the signal's phase be around +/-90 degrees if the SWR is good/similar to the antenna's feed point?  I don't think they can be compared because common mode current could still exist in the shack despite using filters and grounding.

Do the measurements I took of the antenna system indicate any problems?  I was concerned about the RL being more than 20, but from what I've read, larger values are better and track with the value of SWR.  I am looking for a sanity check and have included the measurements, below.


Thank you for your time and interest in my question.



The "phase" in the table is the Argument of the Complex Reflection Coefficient. It has very little impact on your antenna system, for most purposes an SWR of 1.2:1 is fine at any phase.
Any complex impedance value (R+jX or R+L or R+C etc.) can be converted to a complex reflection coefficient, that would occur in a 50 ohm system.
We usually just look at the magnitude of the reflection coefficient, in the form of VSWR, or Return Loss* in dB. The table shows that the RL and VSWR are essentially constant, they get slightly smaller due to the cable losses.
However as you move down a transmission line, the impedance rotates around the centre of the Smith chart. In your example the impedance changes like this:

60 +  j0 ohms (phase of about zero because it's on the right), becomes
50 - j10 ohms (phase of about -90 because it's at the bottom), and then
45 -  j5 ohms (phase of about -130, bottom left)


Here's a quick Smith Chart I generated showing a couple of similar impedance values. I used an SWR of about 1.5:1 (73 ohms) to make the circle big enough. The coloured lines point to the various positions. Angle is measured from the positive X-axis, counterclockwise. So 68 + j0 ohms is 0 degrees, 45 + j0 ohms is 180 degrees etc.

Also note that no matter how good the matching, how close you get to the centre of the chart, the impedance will always have a "phase" and it will always swing wildly around from -180 to 180. Perhaps more wildly the better you are matched. So as long as the SWR is low, the phase is not important.

When the VSWR is high, the phase of the reflection coefficient matters in two main cases:

if you're trying to design a matching network, you need to know if you need to add L or C, and in parallel or series. Usually you'd look at the value of X, but the phase could also be useful.
if your transmitter is more sensitive to (say) low impedances than high impedances, you might choose to add or remove coax to push the impedance to one side, i.e. get the phase closer to zero, away from 180. One example is a handheld radio of mine, where the service manual showed that it had only current limiting for high-VSWR protection. So it would cut back only if the antenna impedance was too low, but not if it was too high.


Thank you very much for such a fantastic explanation!  It has filled in some gaps in my understanding, and excerpts have been added to my notes! :)

The phase of the signal at a single antenna does not matter at all.
It's of consequence only when more than one antenna is radiating or receiving signals.

The phase in the table isn't that kind of phase. It's the argument of the reflection coefficient, showing whether the impedance is inductive or capacitive. Still not very important unless you're designing a matching network.

@tomnexus As you say, not very important in this case.
